# ckeditor apply styles to selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

Does the CKEditor have some sort of direct api to apply styles to a selection? I'm browsing through the docs, but can't seem to find it. What I need to do, is something like to an inline editor.

```
CKEDITOR.selection.applyCss('fontsize', '15px', 'span');
// or
CKEDITOR.selection.applyCss('color', '#bada55', 'span');
```

I can't predefine the styles, as the value in fontsize, color, line-height, letter-spacing, or whatever, is unknown to me.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I answered my own question. It's slightly more cumbersome than I was hoping for, but this does the trick:

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style({
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        'style': 'font-size: 20px'
    }
});

editor.applyStyle(style);
```

Found here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style